# maintain form data after a post

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm doing a function that receives some form data and an Excel file which I walk and earned some data to store them in my database. So far so good, the point is that after you post, validate the Excel (good or bad this is independent of what I need) the form data is clear and I would like to keep them selected. The point is that all my code to complete all validations that I have run the following:

```
return $this->redirect(array('admin' => true, 'controller'=>'test', 'action'=>'test'));
```

I'm starting with cake and I think this may be the problem, also if I remove this code, then the data is loaded, the screen goes blank without displaying any error. It is possible, with this code, to keep the form data as they were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to store the data in the session, and then read it:

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$session->write('form-data', $this->request->data());
return $this->redirect(array('admin' => true, 'controller'=>'test', 'action'=>'test'));
```

And then in your controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $post_data = $this->request->data();
} else {
    $session = $this->request->session();
    $post_data = $session->consume('form-data');
}
//do stuff with $post_data
```